# Node csv-parser return variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, return-value, csv-parser

I have this function

```
validarcsv(){

 let text;
 fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    text = result[0].something
    return text;
  });

}
```

and what i'm triyng to do is retrieve the value of the function like this

```
let value = validarcsv();
console.log(value);
```

it's showing me `undefined`
how can i return the value of that function i'm stuck on that one

Comment: because it is an async call, the on('end') is asynchronous and the validarcsv should be treated using promise or async await or if you are using RxJS then through Observables

Answer (score -1):

You return nothing in `validarcsv()`. If you create a variable and assign it to results and return it at the end it should work.